# Java Generics (Wildcards)

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

I have a couple of questions about generic wildcards in Java:

1. What is the difference between `List<? extends T>` and `List<? super T>`?
2. What is a bounded wildcard and what is an unbounded wildcard?

Comment: In the case that [Ted Gao's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/970122/ted-gao) [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9446233/2476755) is deleted (since it was link-only), here is the [blog post](http://ted-gao.blogspot.com/search/label/Java%20Generics) to which it linked.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In your first question, `<? extends T>` and `<? super T>` are examples of bounded wildcards.  An unbounded wildcard looks like `<?>`, and basically means `<? extends Object>`.  It loosely means the generic can be any type.  A bounded wildcard (`<? extends T>` or `<? super T>`) places a restriction on the type by saying that it either has to *extend* a specific type (`<? extends T>` is known as an upper bound), or has to be an ancestor of a specific type (`<? super T>` is known as a lower bound).

The Java Tutorials have some pretty good explanations of generics in the articles [Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/generics/wildcards.html) and [More Fun with Wildcards](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/extra/generics/morefun.html).

Comment: Just to get it right, if A < B and B < C then: <A extends C> is wrong?

Comment: If by A < B, you mean A extends B, then A does extend C.  You wouldn't use that in the wildcard syntax though, you'd say <? extends C> to limit your choices to either A or B.

Comment: and in that case if I say <? super C> what would be the difference?

Comment: Just wanted to recommend another reference on Java Generics: http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/JavaGenericsFAQ.html

Comment: @Pablo: `<? super C>` would mean that your type is restricted to something above `C` in the type hierarchy.  (Sorry for the extremely late reply.  I guess we didn't have comment notifications 2 years ago?)

Answer (score 55):

If you have a class hierarchy `A`, `B` is a subclass of `A`, and `C` and `D` are both subclasses of `B` like below

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends B {}
class D extends B {}
```

Then

```
List<? extends A> la;
la = new ArrayList<B>();
la = new ArrayList<C>();
la = new ArrayList<D>();

List<? super B> lb;
lb = new ArrayList<A>(); //fine
lb = new ArrayList<C>(); //will not compile

public void someMethod(List<? extends B> lb) {
    B b = lb.get(0); // is fine
    lb.add(new C()); //will not compile as we do not know the type of the list, only that it is bounded above by B
}

public void otherMethod(List<? super B> lb) {
    B b = lb.get(0); // will not compile as we do not know whether the list is of type B, it may be a List<A> and only contain instances of A
    lb.add(new B()); // is fine, as we know that it will be a super type of A 
}
```

A bounded wildcard is like `? extends B` where `B` is some type. That is, the type is unknown but a "bound" can be placed on it. In this case, it is bounded by some class, which is a subclass of B.

Comment: I assume `List<? super B>` describes as *List accepts the type that is parent class of class B*? Which is why C and D won't compile hmm?

Answer (score 39):

Josh Bloch also has a good explanation of when to use `super` and `extends` in this [google io video talk](http://sites.google.com/site/io/effective-java-reloaded) where he mentions the **Producer `extends` Consumer `super`** mnemonic.

From the presentation slides:

> Suppose you want to add bulk methods to `Stack<E>`
>
> `void pushAll(Collection<? extends E> src);`
>
> – src is an E producer
>
> `void popAll(Collection<? super E> dst);`
>
> – dst is an E consumer

Comment: I've read Bloch's book, but I still can't see the difference between extends and super in this particular case.

Comment: Watch the video, I think it's pretty clear. Also, I think you should ask another question on this "what's the difference between List<? extends T> and List<? super T>" where you will hopefully get more answers. (if you do, add a link from here)

Comment: Beds--why not include the example in this answer to make it complete and stand alone. Links are ephemeral.

Answer (score 4):

There may be times when you'll want to restrict the kinds of types that are allowed to be passed to a type parameter. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what bounded type parameters are for.

```
Collection<? extends MyObject>
```

means that it can accept all object who have **IS- A** relationship with MyObject (i.e. any object which is a type of myObject or we can say any object of any subclass of MyObject) or a object of MyObject class.

For example:

```
class MyObject {}

class YourObject extends MyObject{}

class OurObject extends MyObject{}
```

Then,

```
Collection<? extends MyObject> myObject;
```

will accept only MyObject or children of MyObject(i.e. any object of type OurObject or YourObject or MyObject, but not any object of superclass of MyObject).

Answer (score 1):

In general,

> If a structure contains elements with a type of the form `? extends E`, we can get elements out of the structure, but we cannot put
>   elements into the structure

```
List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ints.add(1);
ints.add(2);
List<? extends Number> nums = ints;
nums.add(3.14); // compile-time error
assert ints.toString().equals("[1, 2, 3.14]");
```

To put elements into the structure we need another kind of wildcard called `Wildcards with super`,

```
 List<Object> objs = Arrays.<Object>asList(2, 3.14, "four");
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays.asList(5, 6);
    Collections.copy(objs, ints);
    assert objs.toString().equals("[5, 6, four]");

    public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dst, List<? extends T> src) {
          for (int i = 0; i < src.size(); i++) {
                dst.set(i, src.get(i));
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generic wildcards are created to make methods that operate on Collection more reusable.

For example, if a method has a parameter `List<A>`, we can only give `List<A>` to this method. It is a waste for this method's funtion under some circumstances：

1. If this method only reads objects from `List<A>`, then we should be allowed to give `List<A-sub>` to this method. (Because A-sub IS a A)
2. If this method only inserts objects to `List<A>`, then we should be allowed to give `List<A-super>` to this method. (Because A IS a A-super)

Answer (score 0):

learn by example:

consider the `sort()` method in `Collections` class which use both `extends` and `super`:

```
    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list){...}
```

so

**why `<T extends Comparable<...>>`:** becuase we **need** list items (`T`) to be a subclass of the `Comparable` interface.

**why `Comparable<? super T>`:** becuase we **allow** the `Comparable` type
to be a **Comparable of any super type of T**.

Consider

```
interface Comparable<T>{
    public int compareTo(T o);
}

public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list){...}


public static <T extends Comparable<T>> void sort2(List<T> list){...}


class A implements Comparable<A>{
    @Override
    public int compareTo(A o) {
        ...
    }
}

class B extends A {
}

    List<A> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    List<B> listB = new ArrayList<>();

    sort(listA);  //ok
    sort(listB);  //ok
    
    sort2(listA); //ok
    sort2(listB); //Error
```