# Java generics wildcards

Tags: java, generics, bounded-wildcard

```
public interface UnivariateOperator<T> {
    public TimeSeries<T> operateOn(TimeSeries<T> timeseries);
}

public class SamplingOperator<T> implements UnivariateOperator<T>  {    
    @Override
    public TimeSeries<T> sample(TimeSeries<T> timeseries) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way to use wildcards so the sampling operator can work with any type? I don't really want to have to specify the type for the sampling operator...it should work with any typed timeseries.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards Does this not do something similar to what you want ?

Comment: In your code example T is the type of of the TimeSeries so you wouldn't be specifying the type of the SamplingOperator, just the TimeSeries.

Comment: Your question is confusing: The interface has a `operateOn` method, but the subclass has a `sample` method which overrides something.  You want the whole subclass or just `sample` to be independent of type?  Maybe SamplingOperator should not be an implementation of UnivariateOperator.

Comment: Show us some code that demonstrates how you would like to call/use your desired class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, because you need to specify the generic of UnivariateOperator. If you just want a generic method that samples TimeSeries, you will need something like

```
public class TimeSeriesSampler {
    public static <T> TimeSeries<T> sample(TimeSeries<T> timeseries) {
        ...
    }
}
```

but if you want a SamplingOperator to implements UnivariantOperator, you will need to specify the generic. If you still don't want to specify, you could use something as

```
public class SamplingOperator implements UnivariateOperatior<Object> {
    private SamplingOperator(){
    }
    public <T> TimeSeries<T> sample(TimeSeries<T> timeseries) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public TimeSeries<Object> operateOn(TimeSeries<Object> timeseries) {
        ...
    }
 }
```

but you will lose the power of the generic. Another way is

```
public class SamplingOperator<S> implements UnivariateOperatior<S> {
    private SamplingOperator(){
    }
    public <T> TimeSeries<T> sample(TimeSeries<T> timeseries) {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public TimeSeries<S> operateOn(TimeSeries<S> timeseries) {
        return timeseries;
    }
}
```

but it "smells" bad, as the sample method gives a feeling of a class method, instead of an instance one. It's your choice what's bst to do.

Comment: You forgot your return type for your factory method. Also, you cannot `implement UnivariateOperator<? extends Object>` because you're not allowed to use a wildcard when specifying a supertype.

Comment: Just don't use in this way then. Anyway, the factory works. You didn't need to negative the answer u.u

Comment: Your answer is wrong. You cannot even compile your first suggestion. If you edit that part out I'd gladly flip my vote around.

Answer (score 0):

What if you did something like this:

```
public class SamplingOperator<T> implements UnivariateOperator<T>  {   
    private SamplingOperator(){
    }

    @Override
    public TimeSeries<T> sample(TimeSeries<T> timeseries) {
        ...
    }

    public static SamplingOperator<? extends Object> getInstance() {
        return new SamplingOperator<Object>();
    }
}
```

This ensures that any instance of `SamplingOperator` will be able to accept any type of `TimeSeries` as an argument to its `sample` method.

There are probably better solutions out there, but this one will work.

Answer (score -2):

```
implements UnivariateOperator<Object>
```

Comment: Then it would only work with `TimeSeries<Object>`, and `TimeSeries<AnyClassHere>` is not type compatible with `TimeSeries<Object>`.

Comment: You can make it compatible with anything if you change <Object> to <? extends Object>

Comment: Have you actually tried it? You cannot implement something with a wildcard.