# Java wildcards don't allow type-casting

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, upcasting

```
interface Message<T, L> {
}

interface Foo<T> {
    void frob(Message<T, Foo<?>> message);
}

class AuxiliaryFoo implements Foo<Integer> {
    @Override
    public void frob(Message<Integer, Foo<?>> message) { }
}

class MainFoo implements Foo<Object> {
    @Override
    public void frob(Message<Object, Foo<?>> message) {
        new AuxiliaryFoo().frob(new Message<Integer, MainFoo>() {});
    }
}
```

The Java compiler tells me that `actual argument < anonymous Message< Integer, MainFoo >> cannot be converted to Message< Integer, Foo< ?>> by method invocation conversion`.

Why?

And what can be converted to Message< Integer, Foo< ?>> ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use `<? extends Foo<?>>`

```
interface Foo<T> {     
    void frob(Message<T, ? extends Foo<?>> message); 
}
```

Also, something worthy to keep in mind when dealing with generics is the PECS rule: [Producer Extends, Consumer Super](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards) though it doesn't directly belong here, but I can't say that it doesn't belong here at all..

Comment: Oh, a double wildcard. It worked, thanks! Also, I doubt PECS quite applies here.

Comment: I just mentioned PECS because it's worth keeping in mind, I'll edit the answer to reflect this.