# Role of generics in the return type of a method

Tags: java

I have a marker interface

```
public interface AbcdeedObject {

}
```

I have another interface that has a import of previous interface like this

```
import com.abc.AbcdeedObject;

public interface AbcObjectsGetter
{
    public List<? extends AbcdeedObject> getObjects(File filePath )throws Exception;
}
```

I have a class that implement AbcObjectsGetter interface as shown below

```
public class AbcObjectsGetter implements AbcObjectsGetter
{ 

    //implement the method defination
    public List<? extends AbcdeedObject> getObjects(File updatedFile) throws Exception {

    }
}
```

Please advise me about what is the role of generic here `List<? extends AbcdeedObject>` in the return type.

Comment: It's not clear what the question is here.  Do you know what generics are?  Do you know why `List` has a generic parameter?  Do you understand wildcards?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Generics (Wildcards)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Comment: @PaulBellora I agree, the question could be answered

Answer (score 1):

Every implementation of `getObjects()` must return a list of `AbcdeedObject` or a list of objects of a subclass of `AbcdeedObject`.

In short form it is guaranteed that the returned list only contains instances of `AbcdeedObject` (theoretically).