# Using Java Generics with HashMap

Tags: java, generics

I have a class B and C which both extends class A:

```
public class B extends A {...}
public class C extends A {...}
```

How can I use Java generics with a HashMap this way?

```
B b = new B();
C c = new C();

Map<String, ? extends A> map = new HashMap<String, A>();

map.put("B", b);
map.put("C", c);
```

Eclipse always shows an error:

> The method put(String, capture#1-of ? extends A) in the type
>   Map is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String, B)

and

> The method put(String, capture#1-of ? extends A) in the type
>   Map is not applicable for the
>   arguments (String, C)

Comment: Just use `Map<String, A>`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just change the type of the `HashMap` to `<String, A>`

```
Map<String, A> map = new HashMap<String, A>();
```

Comment: Well, I did that... but what are then wildcards for? 
List<Apple> appleList = new ArrayList<Apple>();
List<? extends Fruit> list = appleList;  ?

Comment: Please, refer to the official doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html. It has an interesting explanation about wildcards. There is also a explanation on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards (see all the answers). Well, if the answer was helpful and solved your problem, don't forget to check it as accepted.