# Why are generics said to be invariant when "? extends Klass" is allowed?

Tags: java, generics

In Java, its said that:

```
String[] is subtype of Object[]
```

so arrays are said to be covariant. But for generics they say:

```
List<X> will not be subType of List<Y>.
```

and hence its invariant. But the question is, "*are generics really invariant*"?

For example, if I give:

```
List<? extends Exception>
```

this means that the list can take the *subtype* of `Exception`, say for example this is valid:

```
List<? extends Exception> k = new ArrayList<NumberFormatException>();
```

Then why Generics are said to be invariant?

Comment: maybe, because String is actually substype of Object, but X might be and might be NOT subtype of Y, because it's generic... just guessing

Comment: my comment is an answer to your question, not to `why a close vote?` :)

Comment: I'm hesitating to call it a duplicate but I think that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards) and the Java tutorial linked in the accepted answer explain the issue quite well.  I think the major source of confusion is that the wildcard bounds the *type of the container* and not the type of the container elements.

Comment: People voting to close as unclear what you're asking don't understand about covariant, invariant and generics, so instead of voting to close they should be reading on these topics and keep the question open to learn something.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Please don't make assumptions about people's motives and understanding.  I was the one who voted to close as unclear, and (1) the original version of this question ended with an incomplete sentence, and at that time it had not been edited; and (2) the question at first appeared to me to be asking us to read other people's minds--i.e. why do people call generics "invariant" when there's one flavor of them that isn't?  So maybe I was too quick on the trigger, but you were too quick to make some rather inaccurate assumptions about "why".

Comment: @ajb if it was unclear but could be fixed, then you should leave a comment about it altogether with your vote to close (unless the question is unsalvageable). The question is fixed now, so the vote to close should be reversed. There's no point on continue arguing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> `List<? extends Exception> k = new ArrayList<NumberFormatException>();`
>
> this means that the list can take the subtype of Exception

Not quite. You can *assign* to `k` a `List` -- or any of its subtype, as you have `ArrayList` -- in this case, of any subtype of `Exception`.

But you cannot *add* to `k` any subtype of `Exception`, or anything for that matter, because `k` is a `List` of **some unknown subtype** of `Exception`. For example,

```
k.add(new NumberFormatException());
```

would give an error.

Retrieval is also restricted to the known type:

```
NumberFormatException e1 = k.get(0); // error
Exception e2 = k.get(0); // ok, anything in k must be an Exception
NumberFormatException e3 = (NumberFormatException) k.get(0); // ok, but the usual downcast issues exist
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are covariant in java, but they *should not be*. This is just one of many design flaws in java language in general and typing system in particular. 
Consider this code:

```
public void messUp(Object objects[]) { objects[0] = "foo"; }
Integer ints[] = new Integer[] {1,2,3};
messUp(ints);
```

This compiles without warning, but throws `ArrayStoreException` when executed.

To answer your question, `List<T>` is invariant, because `List<String>` is not a subclass of `List<Object>`. The "extends" keyword is used to *constrain* the type parameter, but doest not affect the variance: `<T> void foo(List<T>)` means that you can pass a list of elements of any type to `foo`, `<T extends Exception> void foo(List<T>)` means the same thing, except it constrains the type parameter `T`, such that it must be a subclass of `Exception`.

This does not make `List<T>` a subclass of `List<Exception>`, they are still two different classes.  If it was a subclass, you could do the same trick with it that I did with arrays above:

```
<T extends Exception> void foo(List<T> exceptions) { 
    List<Exception> l = exceptions;
    l.add(new RuntimeException());       
}
```

But this will not compile, because `List<T>` cannot be assigned to `List<Exception>` (because it's not a subclass);

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer to your question is a semantic one.
`List<Object>` is not a supertype for `List<String>`.  `Collection<String>` is its supertype, while `ArrayList<String>` is one of its possible subtypes.

Putting it in another way :

```
 Object[] array = new String[2]; //is a valid declaration.
 List<Object> list = new ArrayList<String>(); //is not.
```