# Why not Java allow to assign a List<String> object into a List<Object> object?

Tags: java, generics, collections

May be very stupid question but still I want to clear this concept. Please help me.

```
    List<Object> myObjectArrayList=new ArrayList<Object>();
    Object myObject=new Object();
    myObjectArrayList.add(obj);
    myObjectArrayList.add("My String");
```

Here using Java's Generics features I set the type of the collection as String.
But myObjectArrayList can add **myObject** into the list as Object class is the parent class of all the classes in Java by default.
Now

```
    List<String> myStringArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    myObjectArrayList = myStringArrayList;
```

When I am doing 
**myObjectArrayList = myStringArrayList;** I am getting the compilation error:

```
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to List<Object>
```

Why not Java allow to assign a List< String > object into a List< Object >? My question is if I have a list of parent class and list of child class, why Java does not allow us to assign the child class list object into parent class list object?

Comment: Because an type Object is not a type String, so you can't assign that

Answer (score 1):

One word: Heredity.

A String is an Object, but an Object don't have to be a String.
The ordinary example is the point and the particle. A particle is a point with mass. A particle is a point with something more. So you can say that a particle is a point with mass zero, but not the point is a particle.
You have a collection of point, but then you want that the collection of point were a collection of particle. This is the mistake with `List<Object>` and `List<String>`.
The reverse is good, but that you try not.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler doesn't let you to do this. You declared your list as `List<Object>` you can't assign it to `String`:

```
  List<Object> myObjectArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); // doesn't compile
```

You have to use wildcards for it [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards).

Comment: I already mentioned that I will get the compilation error :Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<String> to List<Object>