# What's the purpose of wild cards in java?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, wildcard

How does the wildcards mentioned below work?

```
<? extends >
<? super >
<? >
```

Which instances would i be able to use them?

Comment: You can see complete documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html

Comment: Welcome to one of the most difficult concepts in Java ;) Personally I've been doing generics in Java for now quite a few years and still cannot come with a clear explanation of it all

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards