# Generics adding subclasses to array

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a class **B** which extends **A**. **A** stores a list of **AItem** and **B** stores a list of **BItem**

In 'A' I have an *ArrayList* which uses [**? extends AItem**] .

I assume this means that I can use this ArrayList for objects of any type that extends AItem.

So in my B class I have a method add(..) which adds a BItem to the items.

I assumed this would work because the items arrayList can hold a list of any object that extends from AItem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class A {
    public ArrayList<? extends AItem> items;
}

public class B extends A{

    public void add(BItem i) {

        this.items.add(i); //compile error here
    } 
}

//items :
class AItem {}
class BItem extends AItem{}
```

How would I get this to work?

My compile error looks like this :

> The method add(capture#2-of ? extends AItem) in the type
>   ArrayList is not applicable for the
>   arguments (BItem)

Comment: You can't add items to an list of unknown type

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add to List<? extends Number> data structures?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2776975/how-can-i-add-to-list-extends-number-data-structures)

Comment: Very good question. I stay tunned for answers but I think that you need to initialize the arrayList with some class.

Comment: You need to use `ArrayList<? super AItem>` [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You probably don't need to use generics here. Having the list of type `AItem` in class `A` should be fine (I would also declare it of type `List` instead of `ArrayList` for best practices):

```
class A {
    public List<AItem> items;
}

class B extends A {

    public void add(BItem i) {

        this.items.add(i);
    } 
}
```

The problem with `? extends AItem` is that the compiler cannot guarantee that the actual type of the elements is `AItem` or `BItem`. It could be another subclass `CItem` in which case the type safety is broken.

There *is* another approach to designing the class hierarchy with generics, in which you set the type parameter in the parent class and set it to the appropriate subclass (`BItem`) in the extended class `B`:

```
class A<T extends AItem> {
    public ArrayList<T> items;
}

class B extends A<BItem>{

    public void add(BItem i) {

        this.items.add(i);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing `extends` with `super`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class A {
    public ArrayList<? super AItem> items;
}

public class B extends A{

    public void add(BItem i) {

        this.items.add(i); //compile error here
    } 
}

//items :
class AItem {}
class BItem extends AItem{}
```

You may find more details about the reason behind this behavior, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
public ArrayList<? super AItem> items;
```

and you can add to the list now

but you will not be able to do

```
public class B extends A{
 .....

   public BItem getOne(int idx) {
     return this.items.get(idx);

   }
}
```

jvm doesn't know what will be actually in the list.

you can generify the A class

```
class  A<T> {
    public ArrayList<T> items;
}
```

then define your B class as

```
public class B extends A<BItem>{

    public void add(BItem i) {

        this.items.add(i); 
    } 
}
```