# What does the question mark mean in Comparable<?>

Tags: java, sorting, generics, comparable

I am working on generics and sorting algorithms and my professor has provided us with a template to base our sorting classes on. However, I am confused on what the following means:

```
public interface Sort<T extends Comparable<?>>
```

I have another class (MergeSort)

```
public class MergeSort<T extends Comparable<?>> implements Sort<T> {
```

however, with that class title I cannot use the follow line of code

```
if (l.get(leftIndex).compareTo(r.get(rightIndex)) < 0)
```

as the compareTo gives me an error of

```
The method compareTo(capture#1-of ?) in the type Comparable<capture#1-of ?>
is not applicable for the arguments (T)
```

but if I change the question mark of `Comparable<?>` to `Comparable<T>`, it can work. However, I don't understand the logic or reasons behind this if anyone can help please. Thank you!

Other information: My professor will provide us with an `ArrayList<Integer>` of Integers and we must initialize our sorting classes to make that a `LinkedList<T> = new LinkedList<>()` in our methods.

Thank you!

Comment: [Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html).

Comment: Looks like a mistake to me. It should probably be `<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Generics (Wildcards)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Comment: @shmosel I'm not sure what to do then if it is a mistake. It's part of his package that includes a class for JUnit4 testing.

Comment: @shmosel I added my own "compare" method and compares two objects and made sure they were instanceof Integer or Long, etc