# Generics - Why don't some versions work?

Tags: java, generics

This code is taken from the OCP textbook. Why do versions 1 and 2 of the addSound method not compile but versions 3 and 4 compile? Compilation error message is "add(capture ) in List cannot be applied to java.lang.String"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("tweet");
    List<Object> objects = new ArrayList<>(strings);
    addSound(strings);
    addSound(objects);
}

//version 1
public static void addSound(List<?> list) {
    list.add("quack");
}

//version 2
public static void addSound(List<? extends Object> list) {
    list.add("quack");
}

//version 3
public static void addSound(List<Object> list) {
    list.add("quack");
}

//version 4
public static void addSound(List<? super String> list) {
    list.add("quack");
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Comment: Doesn't the book explain it?

Comment: The book says unbounded and upper bounded generics are immutable but doesn't explain further.

Comment: I looked at that answer @E_net4 but there they explain how to use the generics. I'm more interested in why specific forms can't be used in this case. I hope that's sufficient to warrant a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to ask is whether the compiler can be *certain* that `list`'s element type is consistent with `String`:

1. `<?>` -- the type is unknown. It could be `Integer`, for example. We can't know that `String` fits. `new List<Integer>().add("quack")` wouldn't compile, so neither can this.
2. `<? extends Object>` -- again, the type is unknown. All classes extend `Object`. So again it could be `Integer`.
3. `<Object>` - No generics here. `String` is a subclass of `Object`. `new List<Object>().add("quack")` works, so this compiles.
4. `<? super String>` this is unknown, with the condition ("*bounds*") that it's a superclass of of `String`. Since we know that `String extends Object`, this type could only be `Object` or `String`. `List<Object>().add("quack")` is OK, and `List<String>().add("quack")` is OK, so this compiles.

The reasoning for number 4, of course applies to more complex type hierarchies:

`BufferedInputStream` extends `FilterInputStream` extends `InputStream` extends `Object`. `InputStream` implements the interfaces `Closeable` and `AutoCloseable`.

So `<? super FilterInputStream>` matches `Object`,`InputStream`,`FilterInputStream`, `Closeable` and `AutoCloseable`.

So a `List<? super FilterInputStream> l` could be a `List<Closeable>` or it could be a `List<InputStream`>, etc. But all you know for sure is that you can `l.add(new FilterInputStream())` or, since it's a subclass `l.add(new BufferedInputStream())`

Answer (score 2):

In Java you have type safety and type erasure. Both concepts are the reason why version 1 and version 2 are not working.

You can not add anything to `List<?>` since you have no clue on what kind of objects are inside the list. It could be possibly be a List of `Integer` or `String` for example.

```
public static void addSound(List<?> list) {
    list.add("quack"); // does not work since List<?> can be anything - type safety not guaranteed
}
```

The Java compiler removes all types on run time which is called type erasure e.g. `List<String>` will be `List` and `List<Integer>` will also be `List` - so you can not differentiate them. You might see it in the bytecode but that is irrelevant here. That's the reason why version 2 is not working

```
//version 2 - has the same type erasure as version 3
public static void addSound(List<? extends Object> list) {
    list.add("quack");
}

//version 3
public static void addSound(List<Object> list) {
    list.add("quack");
}
```

The version 2 also does not work because of type safety once again. See this answer for [generic bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Comment: Murat knows best :D