# Generic list type with question mark

Tags: java

I am having trouble interpreting/understanding the generic type of a Java List:

```
List<? extends Command> myVar = client.performAction(actionParams);
```

How is the generic type `? extends Command` called, like is there a name for it? What exactly is this type? Is it a `Command` object? Or does this mean that it only accepts classes extending `Command`? What is my advantage using this sort of construct? In what Java version was this type of construct integrated?

Comment: That is called a [wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html)

Comment: ? is called a wildcard operator. List<? extends Command> implied, this list can only contain the subclasses of the Command type. Also, since it is using a wildcard operator, your List, myVar.add() call will be cause compilation error.

Comment: Please check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/252055/5180017) StackOverflow question

Comment: @akshayapandey List<Command> also implies the list can only contain instances of command or subclasses thereof.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the answers. Took some time to read through all of them. Indeed the PECS post already answers this matter, so I will let this be the answer.

Answer (score 9):

[**Upper-bounded**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html) wildcards are used to relax the type-restriction of objects you can use. In this case you accept everything that **extends/implements** the `Command` type.

Comment: Nice answer +1! ;-) many people forget that interfaces are also taken into account

Answer (score 4):

The important point about  `List<? extends Command>` is  that it's an *abstract* type.  You can't write `new List<? extends  Command>()` and expect something to get created.  There are two reasons.

- `List` is an interface,  with concrete implementations such as `ArrayList`,  `LinkedList` and others.
- The wildcard in the type parameter, which means "this could be any type that's a subtype of `Command`, including `Command` itself".

That means that a variable of type `List<? extends Command>`  can reference an object of any of these concrete types

- `ArrayList<Command>`
- `LinkedList<SpecialCommand>`
- `CopyOnWriteArrayList<ImportantCommand>`

and numerous other combinations.  Assuming of course that `SpecialCommand` and `ImportantCommand` are subtypes of `Command`.

When you create an object that that variable is going to refer to, you need to be explicit about what concrete type it is.  For example

```
List<? extends Command> myCommandList = new ArrayList<SpecialCommand>();
```

Once you've done that, of course, you can call some of the usual `List` methods on `myCommandList`, such as

```
Command firstCommand = myCommandList.get(0);
```

which is fine, because we know that whatever objects are in the list, they'll all be some type of `Command`.  But you can't do things like

```
SpecialCommand mySpecialCommand = new SpecialCommand();
myCommandList.add(mySpecialCommand);
```

because the compiler has no way of knowing that you're adding the right kind of object to the list.  At this point, `myCommandList` could equally be a `LinkedList<ImportantCommand>`, or similar, and adding a `SpecialCommand` to it needs to be prevented by the compiler.

That means you should only use the type `List<? extends Command>` if you have a variable where

- you don't care what kind of list it is (`ArrayList`, `LinkedList` or whatever)
- you don't care what kind of `Command` is in the list
- you're not going to be trying to add anything to the list.

That means you won't usually use it for a local variable or a field.  It's more likely to be a method parameter, where the things passed in might be `LinkedList<ImportantCommand>` or whatever else; but all you'll be doing in that method is getting objects out of the list, and doing `Command` type operations on them.

Generics have been in Java since Java 5, including wildcards.

Comment: Does being `ArrayList` or `LinkedList` has anything to do with the generic here?

Comment: Not really, but it's one of the two factors that make this an _abstract_ type, instead of something you can instantiate.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the generic type `? extends Command` called, like is there a
>   name for it?

These are called generic [wildcards](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html).

> What exactly is this type? Is it a `Command` object?

It's only used to check variable assignments at compile time. At runtime generics are [erased](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) and interpreted as `List myVar = client.performAction(actionParams);`

> Does this mean that it only accepts classes extending `Command`?

You could only say `List<Command> myVar = client.performAction(actionParams);` and it would accept any object that is type of `Command` or a subclass of command.

`List<? extends Command> myVar` controls the variable assignment. So you could assign only the following generics to `myVar`. The following assignments are all valid, assuming that SubCommand extends Command:

```
myVar = new ArrayList<SubCommand>
myVar = new ArrayList<Command>
```

When declaring collection with wildcard generic, it also can become [read-only](http://What%20is%20my%20advantage%20using%20this%20sort%20of%20construct?). For example `myVar.add(new SubCommand());` will result a compiler error.

> What is my advantage using this sort of construct?

Originally Java did not include generics. It was added in Java 5.0 to allow type restriction of Java collections, like `List`, `Set`, `Map`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have asked many questions at once, let me recapitulate:

- Generics are vital when you implement data structures, containers or algorithm that you want to use on different objects without having to rewrite the whole code
- If I remember correctly generic where introduced in **Java 5.0**, 
  before having generics in Java you could still create flexible data structure containing `Object` objects but you would have to `cast` to final type and use `instanceOf` in a lot of places in your code. Generics were thus introduced to ease this problem and to simplify the code.
- As it has already being said by [NiVeR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1383240/niver), `?` is a wildcard operator and `List<? extends Command>` would restrict the `List` to contain objects that **extends or implements** the class or the interface `Command` **to enforce constraints on the object interface**.

Answer (score 1):

`List<? extends Command>` is called upper-bound wildcard (which many answers had already addressed this). In general, no one would declare his or her list like this; this is mainly used in methods (more commonly, in static methods).

`List<? extends Command>` refers to a list that holds *one specific* type of `Command` (i.e. one particular subclass). Since it's an unknown subclass type, at compile time, you will not be able to add anything. Your IDE will probably resolve `add` method to `add(null e)`.

`List<Command>`, though seemingly similar, refers to a list that holds anything, as long it is a `Command` (or subclassed from `Command`).

Example:

```
List<? extends Command> commands = new ArrayList<FooCommand>();
commands.add(new FooCommand()); // Not allowed at compile time

List<Command> commands = new ArrayList<>();
commands.add(new FooCommand());
commands.add(new BarCommand());
```

Example of when it is used:

```
public static void doSomethingToCommands(List<? extends Command> commands) {
    commands.forEach(this::doSomething);
}

List<FooCommand> fooCommands = getFooCommands();
doSomethingToComamnds(fooCommands); // Allowed

List<Command> commands = getRandomCommands();
doSomethingToComamnds(commands); // Not allowed.
```