# Lambda with wildcard generic type

Tags: generics, lambda, java-8

In java I have the following lambda:

```
Function<? extends Number, Boolean> f = i -> true;
```

Next I want to use this lambda the following way:

```
public <T extends Number> Boolean use(T n) {
  return f.apply(n);
}
```

But the compiler gives 'incompatible types: T cannot be converted to capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Number'

So what is the reason and how can I use my defined function?

Comment: read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with applying `Function<? extends Number, Boolean> f = i -> true;` in your `<T extends Number> Boolean use(T n)` method is that you may assign to `f` a function that takes arguments of one sub-class of `Number` (say `Double`) while your `use` method will attempt to pass to it an instance of another sub-class of `Number` (say `Integer`).

You can change your `Function` definition to

```
Function<Number, Boolean> f = i -> true;
```

which will accept any type the extends `Number` as argument.

Or you can define both the `Function` and the method in a single generic class, which would make sure the arguments passed to `use()` must match the argument expected by `f`:

```
class Generic<T extends Number> {
    Function<T, Boolean> f = i -> true;

    public Boolean use(T n) {
        return f.apply(n);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You want that to "consume" elements via the `Function` the definition should be:

```
static Function<? super Number, Boolean> f = i -> true;
```

The thing is that those definitions are unrelated, you may provide a `Function` of some type that extends Number, while your `use` method might use some *other* type that extends Number.

Either create a single class wrapping those two together (like Eran has shown); or declare your `Function` that will take `Number`; or anything that can be at least a `Number` via `? super Number`