# Abstract method with different parameters Java

Tags: java, generics

```
public abstract class CommonClass {

      abstract void send(<what should i put here???>) {}
    }   

 public class ClassA extends CommonClass {

      void send(List<Comments> commentsList) {
            // do stuff
      }
    }

 public class ClassB extends CommonClass {

      void send(List<Post> postList) {
            // do stuff
      }
    }
```

I am new to OODP, I am trying to have a method that is able to take in any kind of List data so that I can abstract things out. How can i do this?

Comment: Take a look at generics in java https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Comment: You might find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards

Comment: Are `Post` and `Comments` implementing or extending a common Object?

Comment: Don't name the class `Comments`, it should be `Comment`

Comment: @AndrewTobilko And to elaborate on Andrew's point, `ClassA` and `ClassB` aren't very intuitive either. Maybe `CommentSender` and `PostSender`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make it generic on some type `T`. Like,

```
public abstract class CommonClass<T> {
    abstract void send(List<T> al);
}
```

And then, to implement it - use the generic. Like,

```
public class ClassA extends CommonClass<Comments> {
    @Override
    void send(List<Comments> commentsList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class ClassB extends CommonClass<Post> {
    @Override
    void send(List<Post> postList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Also, as discussed in the comments, your class names could be improved to be more intuitive; something like,

```
public abstract class AbstractSender<T> {
    abstract void send(List<T> al);
}
```

and then

```
public class CommentSender extends AbstractSender<Comment> {
    @Override
    void send(List<Comment> commentsList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class PostSender extends AbstractSender<Post> {
    @Override
    void send(List<Post> postList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

That has the advantage(s) of being more readable and easier to reason about (I can tell what a `PostSender` does by reading the name, `ClassB` not so much).

**Finally**, this looks like a case where an interface would work since your `abstract class` is purely virtual (and should be preferred since you can implement multiple interface, but can only extend from a single parent class);

```
public interface ISender<T> {
   void send(List<T> al);
}

public class CommentSender implements ISender<Comment> {
    @Override
    void send(List<Comment> commentsList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

public class PostSender implements ISender<Post> {
    @Override
    void send(List<Post> postList) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: I am using Springboot, why does it complain that "Cannnot resolve symbol T"?

Comment: @Desmond did you define T to be a type parameter in your CommonClass and did you define in your classes inheriting from CommonClass what T has to be? (Double check with answer above)

Comment: @Desmond What Java compiler level have you set? Generics require Java 5+ (which was released in 2004). Also, did you use the code **exactly** as in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve this, you can take multiple approaches, I would suggest looking into Generics: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

With that said, there is one approach that is the most elegant and simple: you can supply a `List<T>` where `T` is a generic type.

```
public abstract class CommonClass<T> {

      abstract void send(List<T>) {}

}   

 public class ClassA extends CommonClass<Comment> {

      void send(List<Comments> commentsList) {
            // do stuff
      }
}

 public class ClassB extends CommonClass<Post> {

      void send(List<Post> postList) {
            // do stuff
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of generics. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

---

### Example

The abstract class

```
public abstract class CommonClass {
    public abstract <T> void send(List<T> data);
}
```

Its child

```
public class Child extends CommonClass {

    public <T> void send(List<T> data) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

### Retrieving the list's contents

Retrieving the generified list's contents is similar to retrieving any list's contents. In the scope of the method, "T" is a type of object contained in the list.

```
for (T t : data) {
    // to check if t is a string
    if (t instanceof String) {
        // code
    }
}
```

You can also use lambdas to retrieve every element in the list.

Comment: Why would you introduce your own generic parameter when there is no need for this? This can also introduce problems in the future, as probably there is logic for a specific Type (Class), now you restrict the user of this.

Comment: Well I assumed that the he won't need to use the specific type outside of the class since he didn't mention. But yes, it's better to generify the class if there is a necessity use it in different methods and fields.