# Defining Linked list in Java

Tags: java

```
private List<Manufacturer> productManufacturer = new LinkedList<Manufacturer>();
```

I am not able to understand why `<>` this symbol is here and `Manufacturer` inside it to define a LinkedList in Java.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards)

Answer (score 3):

### Generics

Please read about [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

```java
  private List<Manufacturer> productManufacturer = new LinkedList<>();
```

Assuming `Manufacturer` is a java class/interface/enum type, the above line defines a `List` that can hold only objects of type `Manufacturer` or its subclass types