# How can Collection.reverseOrder() used in Arrays.<Integer>sort()

Tags: java, generics

I see the Collections.reverseOrder() method returns a type `ReverseComparator`, which implements `Comparator<Comparable<Object>>`, as below

```
    private static class ReverseComparator implements Comparator<Comparable<Object>>, Serializable {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 7207038068494060240L;
            static final Collections.ReverseComparator REVERSE_ORDER = new Collections.ReverseComparator();
  ....
```

in below valid code:

```
var comparator = Collections.reverseOrder();
Arrays.sort(new Integer[]{2, 4}, comparator);
```

the 2nd parameter of the sort method is of type `Comparator<? super Integer>`.

I think when the sort method get called, the `Comparator<Comparable<Object>>` type is conceptually convertible to `Comparator<? super Integer>`, thus I wonder how a `Comparable<Object>` becoming super type of `Integer`, although I know `Integer` implements `Comparable<Integer>`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Generics (Wildcards)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/252055/java-generics-wildcards) `? super Integer` means that it could be `Integer` or a supertype of `Integer`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bit of compiler trickery. In Java, generics are stripped when compiling source code (.java) to JVM bytecode (.class). For this particular class, `ReverseComparator`, it actually does not care about the generic type of the object that's being compared. It does not use the generic in any way, and has therefore its generic defined using the parent of all classes, `Object`. Then, when the method `reverseOrder()` is called, the particular instance of `ReverseComparator` is casted to the particular type from the calling context, inferred by the compiler, or by the developer's specification using the `Collections.<MyClass>reverseOrder()` syntax.

The reason the compiler accepts this unsafe cast from Object -> T, is because of `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` above this method, allowing unchecked casts.

Comment: Your answer is not right, actually I changed "Arrays.sort(new Integer[]{2, 4}, comparator);" to two lines as "var comparator = Collections.reverseOrder(); Arrays.sort(new Integer[]{2, 4}, comparator);", it is a valid code and running as expected, you answer is not able to explain that.

Comment: Sure, that is because the generic type `? super T` is used, basically accepting T, and all its parent classes, including the parent of all classes, `Object`.

Comment: The type parameter T in `Comparator<T>`  is substituted by `Comparable<Object>` from `reverseOrder()`, the type parameter of 2nd parameter of sort() method is `? supert T`(`Comparator<? supert T>`), it still goes back to my question is `Comparable<Object>` convertible to `? supert Integer` ?

Comment: Yes, in the type set `? super T` is `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `comparator` has type `Comparator<? super Integer>` (or `Comparator<Integer>`; it doesn't matter for our purposes). The compiler sees that you want the `Collections.reverseOrder()` method to return the type `Comparator<? super Integer>`, so it infers the `T` in the call to `Collections.reverseOrder()` that will make it return a `Comparator<? super Integer>`. It might, for example, infer `T = Integer`, so the `Collections.reverseOrder()` call will return a `Comparator<Integer>` (or it is also valid to infer `T = Object`, so that `Collections.reverseOrder()` will return a `Comparator<Object>`; it doesn't matter either way). As for how the `Collections.reverseOrder()` gets a value of the type `Comparator<Integer>`, that's an internal implementation detail of the library.

In the implementation of the library you are looking at, it has a single global comparator instance, `ReverseComparator.REVERSE_ORDER`. But how can `Collections.reverseOrder()` return this no matter what `T` is? For example, it is not possible for something to be `Comparator<Integer>` and `Comparator<String>` at the same time. So basically, the library is lying. `ReverseComparator.REVERSE_ORDER` is declared as some dummy type of comparator (it happens to be `Comparator<Comparable<Object>>`, but it doesn't really matter; it could be `Comparator<Math>` for all we care), and then inside the `Collections.reverseOrder()` method it does an unchecked cast of `ReverseComparator.REVERSE_ORDER` into the right type of comparator that it wants to return (`Comparator<T>`).

This unchecked cast is theoretically "incorrect" because `ReverseComparator` is not actually a `Comparator<T>` for any `T` other than `Comparable<Object>` (and basically nobody ever implements `Comparable<Object>`, so it is basically always "incorrect"). However, generics are erased at runtime (that's why the cast is "unchecked" -- it is not possible to check it at runtime), so it won't cause any exceptions as long as using a `ReverseComparator` as a `Comparator<Integer>` won't lead to any invalid assumptions at runtime. The only thing that a `Comparator<Integer>` needs to do is have a method `compare()` that takes two `Integer`s. `ReverseComparator`'s `compare()` method is able to do that, since `ReverseComparator`'s `compare()` method takes two `Comparable`s, and `Integer`s are `Comparable`s. `ReverseComparator`'s `compare()` method calls the `compareTo()` method on the second argument, passing the first argument; that is valid for `Integer`s, since `Integer`s are comparable to themselves. So this usage is safe, and the lie does not cause any problems.

If I were able to rewrite the `reverseOrder()` API from scratch and implement it in a "safe" way, I would probably do something like this:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> Comparator<T> reverseOrder() {
    return new Comparator<T>() {
        public int compare(T c1, T c2) {
            return c2.compareTo(c1);
        }
    };
}
```

This guarantees that `T` is actually comparable to itself, and doesn't do any unchecked casts. One downside is that it needs to create a new Comparator instance for every call to `reverseOrder()`. (Perhaps using lambdas instead of anonymous classes could avoid that.)